# mysql_num_rows returning wrong value

Tags: php, mysql

```
echo $sql2 = "select uid,username from userstable where username IN(".$usernameStr.")";
$res2 = mysql_query($sql2);
echo "------".mysql_num_rows($res2)."-----";
```

`mysql_num_rows` returns only 1 record which is the last entry but when I run the query in `MySQL` it is returning correct number of records.

Where is the problem?

Comment: With phpMyAdmin how many rows it returns? How is formed $usernameStr? That said mysql_* are deprecated command, better using mysqli_* function or PDO Libraries

Comment: and delete echo before $sql2, maybe is that

Comment: @MarcoMura $usernameStr = 'aaa','bbb'.It return 2 rows while run in mysql.

Comment: Delete the echo before $sql2

Comment: @MarcoMura Done but not working

Comment: Shouldn't be the usernameString wraped around by quotes? `IN('".$usernameStr."')` And why do you use `IN`? Why not `=`?

Comment: @lolka_bolka he is using more than one value inside the var. That said if the var is really 'aaa', 'bbb' it should work

Comment: please use while loop

Comment: while($rs=mysql_num_rows($res2)){ echo $rs['uid'].' '.$rs['uid']; }

Comment: @JoyDas Can you add the code to get $usernameStr

Comment: echo the query, run the php file, copy it from the browser, and use the same query in the mysql editor. It should ideally show the same number of rows

Comment: do you have more than one db in the connection. if yes then apppend the db name to the table. => "select * from db.table"

Answer (score -1):

```
while($rs=mysql_num_rows($res2)){ 
 echo $rs[0].' '.$rs[1];
}
```

Comment: `echo $rs['uid']` will definitely throw warning. And you don't use `mysql_num_rows()` inside while loop which check condition. This code will return true every time.

Comment: @vikram sharma mysql_num_rows($res2) will always be a positive number and no where inside your loop you are updating it.

Comment: @vikram sharma  i think you got confused b/w mysql_fetch_array and mysql_num_rows

Comment: Or perhaps mysql_fetch_assoc since you wanted to use associative arrays